# Docker push: push image once with multiple tags

Tags: docker, tags, push

I have a docker image with three tags `repo:latest`, `repo:v1.1`, `repo:dev`. When I do `docker push repo:v1.1` only one tag will be pushed into repository. Is there a way to make one push with all tags or I need to push-per-tag?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [docker push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) command does not accept several arguments (if ever one wants to push a selection of several tags (not all) in one go), so one needs to push each tag separately, e.g.:

```
for t in latest v1.1 dev; do
    docker push "repo:${t}"
done
```

Otherwise, as mentioned in [@GuillaumePancak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65255100/9164010), one may be interested in relying on the `--all-tags` flag available [from Docker 20.10.0](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#20100).

Note also that it is frequent to consider pushing *several different tags for the same image* (which may be your use case here as well). In this case pushing these tags successively (and not at the same time with several concurrent processes) ensures the `docker push` of the tag synonyms will be almost immediate, after the image has been pushed once with a given tag.

Comment: Why the downvote? `docker push image:tag1 image:tag2` is still not available if ever one wants to push a selection of several tags (not all) in one go. Yet, as pointed out by @GuillaumePancak's answer, the `--all-tags` CLI option can be useful. Will edit my answer to link to this answer as well.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to push **all tags** for an image, you can use the `--all-tags` option:

```
docker image push --all-tags repository/image_name
```

This option is supported for [Docker 20.10 and newer](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2220). The same behaviour can be achieved by omitting `--all-tags` on older versions.

---

More information: [Docker push documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/)

Comment: unfortunately migrating to Docker 20.10+ will indeed introduce a breaking change because only the first tag is pushed, contrary to the previous versions, which is however safer to control what we really want to do

Comment: This generally isn't a good option.  Using `--all-tags` will push all tags *and all images*.  

This means that if you currently did a build of `v1.1.1` and want to push that but last week you built `v1.0.0` that will also get re-pushed.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a [change](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/458#pullrequestreview-57642310) to push multiple image in the same time, which is in review.
But it only adds a loop for the `docker push` instead of parallelizing them.
So right now, the unique solution is to push each tag separately.

Comment: It seems like the PR you mentioned has been closed _without merging_. I also found an other related [pull request](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1021) (closed as well). So, there isn't still any way to push in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

In a script, you can do a loop like this to push all tags for an image; `${1}` is the first parameter passed to the script; like `docker_push myimage`

```bash
for i in $(docker image list --format "{{.Tag}}" "${1}"); do
    docker push "${1}:$i"
done
```